# How to store reference to avoid deconstruct in c#

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism, pass-by-reference

I have a class that uses (system.io.ports.serialport) from another class.

I wanted to create something like this:

```
public class whatever
{

        private ref System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _ser;
        public VT_interface(ref System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serial)
        {
            _ser = ref serial;
        }
}
```

but couldn't do anything that solves my issue (i think all other working ways are deconstructing serial port and that affect the original serial port object.

I say that because after this object gets deconstructed and the only working way I found is to place 'ref serialPort' in all my methods that require using the serial port .. which is obviously something I don't want to (I only want to pass it once at constructor).

Comment: A reference should be good enough.. what do you mean by "*i say that becase after this object get deconstructed*"

Comment: looks like you want to create a `singleton`

Comment: when i use SerialPort.GetPortNames() in main program i get A com port that doesnt exist (existed before constructing my class).. this issue started when i moved my long codes to objects and had to pass serial port..

Comment: this is stupid. its being returned becasue im not closing the connection ... however im still not sure how to create reference of other object and store in variable. so in my classes' methods i always add (ref otherobject) which is annoying.

Comment: @TheGeneral i assume that when (whatever) object get deconstructed it calls the deconstructor of (_ser) ? the code above is not valid with (ref) keyword. i have to remove it.. thats why i wanted to make code with (ref) to avoid deconstructing (_ser) when my class gets deconstructed.